# Why the text keeps stay out of my bubble box?

Tags: css, html

I can't understand why the text I'm trying to get in the bubble box won't be there.

[Here](http://imgbin.org/images/22689.jpg) is the link to a picture of what I see

I'm super newbie and this might be a very stupid question, but I spent like 40 minutes trying to figure out what's wrong.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style type="text/css">

.bubble
{
    position: absolute;
    width: 230px;
    height: 33px;
    text-align: left;
    font-size: 10px;
    line-height: 100px;
    background-color: #00ff00;
    border-radius: 10px;
    margin-top: 100px;
    margin-left: 200px;
}
.bubble:after
{
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    left: 20px;
    top: 33px;
    border: 22px solid;
    border-color: #00ff00 transparent transparent #00ff00;
}

</style>

</head>
        <div class="bubble">im lemon im a little spaghetti</div>
</html>
```

Help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should define `line-height: 33px`, because that is the height of your bubble

See [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bnyvsn8q/)

I suggest you add a bit of padding, so that the text won't be stuck at the left border of the bubble. Like that :

`padding: 0 5px;`

That will add `5px` of padding to the left and to the right, that is a shorthand for :

`padding: 0 5px 0 5px;` which is itself a shorthand for

```
padding-top: 0;
padding-right: 5px;
padding-bottom: 0;
padding-left: 5px;
```

See [updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bnyvsn8q/1/)

Answer (score 0):

Looks like its overlapping. You should look at this example, there are variety of layouts and other css options to accomplish what you're trying to do covering multiple browsers.

http://nicolasgallagher.com/pure-css-speech-bubbles/demo/

Here is the CSS for the first bubble text:

```
.triangle-isosceles {
  position:relative;
  padding:15px;
  margin:1em 0 3em;
  color:#000;
  background:#f3961c; /* default background for browsers without gradient support */
  /* css3 */
  background:-webkit-gradient(linear, 0 0, 0 100%, from(#f9d835), to(#f3961c));
  background:-moz-linear-gradient(#f9d835, #f3961c);
  background:-o-linear-gradient(#f9d835, #f3961c);
  background:linear-gradient(#f9d835, #f3961c);
  -webkit-border-radius:10px;
  -moz-border-radius:10px;
  border-radius:10px;
}

/* Variant : for top positioned triangle
------------------------------------------ */

.triangle-isosceles.top {
  background:-webkit-gradient(linear, 0 0, 0 100%, from(#f3961c), to(#f9d835));
  background:-moz-linear-gradient(#f3961c, #f9d835);
  background:-o-linear-gradient(#f3961c, #f9d835);
  background:linear-gradient(#f3961c, #f9d835);
}
```

The complete CSS: 
http://nicolasgallagher.com/pure-css-speech-bubbles/demo/default.css

Basically you'd put the text inside the

paragraph tag by calling the class:

```
<p class="triangle-isosceles">This only needs one HTML element.</p>
```

@ref: http://nicolasgallagher.com/pure-css-speech-bubbles/demo/